# iterate adding/removing edges and perform calculations networkx

Tags: graph, iteration, networkx

I am working with `networkx 2.5.` in `Jupyter notebook`, `python version 3.6.5` I am working with an indirect graph. I have a graph from which I would like to perform the following steps iteratively

1. Remove one edge,
2. Perform some calculations over the remaining graph (number of connected components, diameter and nodes)
3. Put back the removed edge
4. Remove another edge
5. Repeat the whole procedure until all the edges were deleted once

For instance, I have the following graph:

```
                      'target' : [3, 2 ,4]})
nodes2 = pd.DataFrame({'nodeS' : [1, 2, 3 , 4],
                      'density' : [1, 2, 4, 2],
                      'indiv' : [2, 4, 1, 5]})
G1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges2, 'source', 'target')
nx.set_node_attributes(G1, pd.Series(nodes2.density, index=nodes2.nodeS).to_dict(), "density")
nx.set_node_attributes(G1, pd.Series(nodes2.indiv, index=nodes2.nodeS).to_dict(), 'indiv')
```

I plotted the first graph (G1)
The result looks like [image: G1]
Then I make the calculations over the graph:

```
# largest connected component (it will be necessary for the first calculation after first edge removal)
G1_LCC = G1.subgraph(max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len))
# number of connected components
G1_cc = nx.number_connected_components(G1)
# diameter of largest connected component 
G1_diam = nx.diameter(G1_LCC)
# number of connected nodes 
G1_nodes = len(nx.nodes(G1_LCC))
```

Removing an edge:
I tried the next:

```
e = (1,2)
G2= nx.remove_edge(e)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
 nx.edges_iter(G)
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'remove_edge'
```

This should look like (G2)[image: G2]

Then perform operations on G2

Remove an edge which would look like that:

The third G3, (G3)[image: G3]

and so on, until all the edges have been removed once.

Note: I tried with `edges iter`
 `nx.edges_iter(G)`
but I also got an error
 `AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'edges_iter'`

Is there an iterative/ efficient way to remove the edges, make calculations and put them back? Rather than do it one by one? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`remove_edge` is a method of the `Graph` class, not a top-level function in the library. So `G2 = G1.remove_edge(e).copy()` would be the correct command (you may not need to make a copy if you are adding the edge back in at a later point). `edges_iter` *was* also a method of `Graph` but has been discontinued for `edges`. So `for e in G1.edges()`, **not** `for e in nx.edges_iter(G1)`.

Comment: I tried  ```G2 = G1.remove_edge(e).copy() ```  it  said  ```"Frozen graph can't be modified" ```,  I just made the copy first and it did the trick. About removing the edge, I get ```TypeError: remove_edge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'```  I have tried in several ways,  ```e = [('1', '2')] ```  ```e=(1, 2)```  ```G2 = G2.remove_edge(*e)``` ``` G2.remove_edge(1,2) ``` ```G2.remove_edge[(1,2)]```, but it is always the same error, any idea why?